# Android + Arduino via USB

Tags: arduino, usb, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to communicate with Arduino board (Duemilanove) from Android 3.1 device with USB-host support using Android USB Host API (not in USB Accessory mode).

The questions are:

```
1.how to prepare arduino board (modify firmware) - interruptions or  smth?
2.how to check if its okay with arduino board (f.e. enumerate USB interfaces and verify that it supports needed. what tools can be  used?
3.how to find needed interface (what are interface class/protocol/subclass)
4.what can be the reason when interface cannot be claimed? (faced with that)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30012/android-+-arduino-via-usb/) by [4ntoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/2015/4ntoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should ask this question into the [Arduino forums](http://arduino.cc/forum/).

Anyway, maybe the [Amarino toolkit](http://www.amarino-toolkit.net/) is useful for your application

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0